# Cannot override fun done()

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to save object in background by using Parse.com but I can't override

```
   override fun done(e: ParseException?) {
    //code
                  }
```

I'm getting error: `Modifier 'override' is not applicable to 'local function`
In java I would use:

```
myObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
    public void done(ParseException e) {
      if (e == null) {
        myObjectSavedSuccessfully();
      } else {
       myObjectSaveDidNotSucceed();
      }
   }
  });
```

Here is my whole class

```
class StarterApplication : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        Parse.initialize(Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
                .applicationId(appID)
                .clientKey(null)
                .server(serverUrl)
                .build()
        )

        var exampleObject: ParseObject = ParseObject("ExampleObject")
        exampleObject.put("myString", "fwfwe")
        exampleObject.saveInBackground( {
               override fun done(e: ParseException?) { //here is an error //`Modifier 'override' is not applicable to 'local function`

              }

     })
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some context? What surrounds your first code snippet?

Comment: @zsmb13 Edited topic with code

Comment: Is SaveCallback an interface with one method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do like that:

```
exampleObject.saveInBackground(object : SaveCallback {
    override fun done(e: ParseException?) {
        // Add your code here
    }
})
```

In Java, you declare an anonymous class that extend `SaveCallback`. In Kotlin, you do this with [Object Expressions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot Kevin!

Answer (score 2):

you can also try the simplest solution like this

```
 exampleObject.saveInBackground({ 
 //you code here
  })
```

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions